# How can this code be made to run fast on large sheets of excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CompareSheetsAndLogChangesColumnB()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim cellA As Range, cellB As Range
    Dim pernums As Object
    Dim pernum As String, changeInfo As String
    Dim data1 As Variant, data2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, changeRow As Long
    
    changeRow = 2
    
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    If Not ws3 Is Nothing Then
        ws3.Cells.Clear
    End If
    
    ws3.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Personal Number"
    ws3.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Explanation"
    
    data1 = ws1.UsedRange.Value
    data2 = ws2.UsedRange.Value
    
    Set pernums = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(data1, 1)
        pernum = data1(i, 2)
        If Not pernums.Exists(pernum) Then
            pernums.Add pernum, 0
        End If
    
        ' Call the CompareRows function to compare the entire row
        Dim rowChange As String
    
        rowChange = CompareRows(data1, i, data2, ws2, pernum)
    
        If rowChange <> "" Then
            ws3.Cells(changeRow, 1).Value = pernum
            ws3.Cells(changeRow, 2).Value = rowChange
            changeRow = changeRow + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(data2, 1)
        pernum = Data(i, 2)
        If Not pernums.Exists(pernum) Then
            ws3.Cells(changeRow, 1).Value = pernum
            ws3.Cells(changeRow, 2).Value = "Not Found in the first sheet"
            changeRow = changeRow + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function CompareRows(data1 As Variant, rowIndex As Long, data2 As Variant, ws2 As Worksheet, pernum As String) As String
    ' Initialize an empty change string
    Dim changeDetails As String
    ' Find the corresponding row in the second sheet
    Dim rowNum2 As Long
    rowNum2 = 0
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(data2, 1)
        If data2(i, 2) = pernum Then
            rowNum2 = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Check if the corresponding row was found in the second sheet
    If rowNum2 > 0 Then
        ' Compare each column in the row
        For j = LBound(data1, 2) To UBound(data1, 2)
            ' Check if the column index is within the bounds of data2
            If j <= UBound(data2, 2) Then
                ' Compare the corresponding cell in the second sheet
                If data1(rowIndex, j) <> data2(rowNum2, j) Then
                    Dim header As String
                    header = FindHeader(ws2, data1(1, j))
                    If header <> "Header Not Found" Then
                        ' Concatenate the change details
                        changeDetails = changeDetails & header & ": " & data1(rowIndex, j) & " changed to " & data2(rowNum2, j) & ", "
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        
        ' Remove the trailing comma and space if there were changes
        If Len(changeDetails) > 0 Then
            changeDetails = Left(changeDetails, Len(changeDetails) - 2)
        End If
    End If
    
    ' If the corresponding row was not found in the second sheet, provide an explanation
    If rowNum2 = 0 Then
        changeDetails = "Personal Number not found in the second sheet"
    End If
    
    ' If the row is not found in the first sheet, provide a different explanation
    If rowIndex > UBound(data1, 1) Then
        changeDetails = "Personal Number not found in the first sheet"
    End If
    
    ' Return the change details for the row
    CompareRows = changeDetails
End Function

Function FindHeader(ws As Worksheet, paramValue As Varient) As String
    Dim header As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set header = was.Rows(1).Find(paramValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not header Is Nothing Then
        FindHeader = header.Value
    Else
        FindHeader = "not found"
    End If
End Function
```

This is my code . It works fully and it's all good I just need to make it work more efficiently and make it faster to run and finish larger excel sheets because it takes very long that it's just more time efficient to do it by hand. This code compares two sheets and logs the changes in a third sheet
This is a VBA Code for excel.

Comment: Is `pernum =data(i, 2)` a typo in your question or your actual code?

Comment: In FindHeader there's also `Set header = was.Rows(1).Find(paramValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`, `was` instead of `ws`. Are you sure this was running well/as intended? Another one: `If header <> "Header Not Found"` instead of the `"not found"` used in your FindHeader function.

Comment: Are the columns going to be switched around? Your comparison seems to be based on the idea that nothing seems to have a stable position O.õ

Comment: In the parameter list of `FindHeader` you misspelled `Variant`. The code that you posted doesn't compile -- how could it be "all good"? Is the code that you posted different from your actual code?

Comment: I'd think removing the function calls and put its functionality inside the sub will make it slightly more efficient, albeit less readable (but efficiency is sometimes at the cost of readability)

Comment: `Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")` this line near the top of your code will throw a _Subscript out of range_ error if Sheet3 doesn't exist.  The line `If Not ws3 Is Nothing Then` will never be reached if Sheet3 doesn't exist.

Comment: `i` & `j` aren't declared in `CompareRows` and using `was` instead of `ws` in `FindHeader`.

Comment: If `FindHeader` is called frequently then switching from `Find()` to using `Application.Match()` will speed things up.

Comment: `If j <= UBound(data2, 2) Then` instead of checking this over and over, you can figure out one time what the upper bound of the `j` loop should be.  Also - build a Dictionary for the `pernum` in `data2`, so you don't have to loop to figure out which values are common to both datasets.  If you have a lot of changes to write tow ws3, batch those up by first filling an array with the content, and then writing once to the worksheet.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind FindHeader?  What is it checking for?

Comment: ...it looks like you only log changes if the headers at that position (`j`) are matched?  What if the same headers exist but the column order is changed?

Comment: Vote-to-closers - what the heck?  Opinion-based?  The OP is asking for approaches to *measurably improve* the functioning of their code/process.  How are demonstrable performance improvements "opinion-based".  It's not my "opinion" (for example) that Match is faster than Find - it just is.   Please let's not confuse experience with opinion.

Comment: Hi Tim, It gives me an error called : this key is already associated with an element of this collection on the line RowMap.Add CStr(v), r

Comment: What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be faster.  It uses two dictionaries to map the row positions of each id in the two arrays.  Also uses an array for capturing the output (you might want some smarter way of assigning the initial size for that...) so you can write the results in one assignment.

On my PC comparing two sheets of about 90k rows x 8 columns took just over 3 seconds.

**Note** - I left out the column header check, since I wasn't able to follow the logic you're using for that.  You check to see if the header is also on the second sheet, but you don't verify the header *position* is the same as the first sheet... Using `Find()` is a lot slower than using `Application.Match`, so at least consider testing that change in your existing code.

```vb
Sub CompareSheetsAndLogChangesColumnB()
    Const SHT_A As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SHT_B As String = "Sheet2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim cellA As Range, cellB As Range
    Dim pernums1 As Object, pernums2 As Object, k
    Dim pernum As String, changeInfo As String, sep As String
    Dim data1 As Variant, data2 As Variant, t
    Dim dataOut(1 To 10000, 1 To 2) 'size to max expected lines * 2 maybe
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, changeRow As Long, maxCols As Long, rowNum As Long
    
    t = Timer
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(SHT_A)
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(SHT_B)
    Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    ws3.Cells.Clear
    ws3.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Personal Number"
    ws3.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Explanation"
    
    data1 = ws1.UsedRange.Value
    data2 = ws2.UsedRange.Value
    maxCols = Application.Min(UBound(data1, 2), UBound(data2, 2)) 'max# of cols to compare
    
    'map unique values in col2 to their row indexes
    Set pernums1 = RowMap(data1, 2, 1) '1=skip header row
    Set pernums2 = RowMap(data2, 2, 1)
    changeRow = 0
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(data1, 1)
        pernum = CStr(data1(i, 2))
        
        If Not pernums2.exists(pernum) Then
            AddMessage dataOut, changeRow, pernum, "Not found on sheet " & SHT_B
        Else
            rowNum = pernums2(pernum)
            changeInfo = ""
            sep = ""
            For j = 1 To maxCols
                If data1(i, j) <> data2(rowNum, j) Then
                    changeInfo = changeInfo & sep & "Column '" & data1(1, j) & _
                                  "' changed from '" & data1(i, j) & _
                                  "' to '" & data2(rowNum, j) & "'"
                    sep = ", "
                End If
            Next j
            If Len(changeInfo) > 0 Then AddMessage dataOut, changeRow, pernum, changeInfo
        End If
    Next i
    
    'check for any id's on sheet2 not on sheet1
    For Each k In pernums2
        If Not pernums1.exists(CStr(k)) Then
            AddMessage dataOut, changeRow, CStr(k), "Not found on sheet " & SHT_A
        End If
    Next k
    
    If changeRow > 0 Then 'any changes to log?
       ws3.Range("A2").Resize(changeRow, 2).Value = dataOut
    End If
    
    Debug.Print Timer - t
    
End Sub

'Map unique values in column `idCol` of 2D array `data`
'  to the row index they're found on. Optionally ignore first
'  `skipHeaders` rows in the array
Function RowMap(data As Variant, idCol As Long, _
                Optional skipHeaders As Long = 0) As Object
    Dim r As Long, rStart As Long, v
    Set RowMap = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    rStart = LBound(data, 1) + skipHeaders
    For r = rStart To UBound(data, 1)
        v = data(r, idCol)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then RowMap.Add CStr(v), r 'assumes data in column `idCol` is unique
    Next r
End Function

'add a new "line" to the array `dataOut` and increment the counter `changeRow`
Sub AddMessage(dataOut, ByRef changeRow As Long, pernum As String, msg As String)
    changeRow = changeRow + 1
    dataOut(changeRow, 1) = pernum
    dataOut(changeRow, 2) = msg
End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me an error called : this key is already associated with an element of this collection on the line RowMap.Add CStr(v), r. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: If it does that then your "Personal Number" column is not unique (>1 row for some values).  Exactly how should values be compared in that situation?  If there are multiple rows then which pairs of rows should be compared?

Comment: But it doesn't have duplicate values I checked. It only has unique values

Comment: But if there are only unique values then you wouldn't get that error.  Are you able to share a sample workbook (suitably redacted...) ?

Comment: I fixed it but now it gives me the next error: Subscript out of range on the line if data1 (i, j) <> data2(rowNum, j) Then.

Comment: Sorry - I had an error: should be `maxCols = Application.Min(UBound(data1, 2), UBound(data2, 2))` (not Max)

Comment: Great that you caught that but still even with the change it still gives me the same error 

Comment: What is the value of `j` when it fails?  Is that more than the number of columns of data?  What is the value of `rowNum` ?  Is that more than the number of rows of data you have on Sheet2 ?

Comment: The j continues on after the number of columns.  So maybe the maxCols still dosent work?

Comment: What is the value of `maxCols`, and what is the value of `j` when it fails?

Comment: A couple of things: the two excel sheets have 16 Columns but the maxCols is somehow 40 and it stops because of an error after j is 33 and maxCols is 40.   So it's weird why it doesn't work

Comment: Try specifying the ranges explicitly instead of using `UsedRange` - that's not very reliable.  If your data has no blank rows/columns then (eg) `data1 = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value` would likely be a better approach.

Comment: And if I have possible blank columns?

Comment: At this point I think you need to share a little more information about exactly what your source data looks like.  If it really has blank columns (not even a header?) then that may be an issue.  If columns are in a different order between the two sheets then that's *definitely* a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is written seems OK if it does what you want, but you are recalculating the spreadsheet and repainting the screen every time any change is made from VBA which can be glacially slow!

If you bracket the existing code with disable screen updates and set calculation to manual it should be a **lot** faster. Fast enough may still be a problem though - it is certainly the first thing to try for a quick speed up.

Remember to reset it back to normal when you leave your routine!

Sample code

```
Sub faster()
Application.Calculation = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = xlManual

''your stuff here

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. The part where you assign Range to range is very good and will save you a lot of time.

However there are a few rules for VBA that you can use to make your code faster. And which you should always have in mind when writing new code.

Rule #1. Calculation

Normally, Excel will recalculate all cells, formulas and conditional formatting if a value in a cells or ranges have changed. This may cause your workbook to recalculate too often, which will slow down performance. You can prevent Excel from recalculating the workbook by using the statement:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

At the end of your code, you can set the calculation mode back to automatic with the statement:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Remember, though, that when the calculation mode is xlCalculationManual, Excel doesn't update values in cells. If your macro relies on an updated cell value, you must force a Calculate event, with the .Calculate method like `Worksheets(1).Calculate.`

**Rule #2. ScreenUpdating**

As the colleagues have already mentioned in the comments, you can already get a lot out of this command.

The Problem with VBA is, every time VBA writes data to the worksheet it refreshes the screen image that you see. Refreshing the image is a considerable drag on performance. The following command turns off screen updates.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
```

At the end of the macro use the following command to turn screen updates back on.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
```

Rule #3 With statement

You will often manipulate the same object more than once. You can save time and improve performance by using the With statement to perform several actions on a given object in one shot.

The With statement utilized in the following example tells Excel to apply all the formatting changes at one time:

```
With Range("A1").Font
.Bold = True
.Italic = True
.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
End With
```

Exmaple for the With Statement:

Your Code

```
  For i = 2 To UBound(data2, 1)
            pernum = Data(i, 2)
            If Not pernums.Exists(pernum) Then
                ws3.Cells(changeRow, 1).Value = pernum
                ws3.Cells(changeRow, 2).Value = "Not Found in the first sheet"
                changeRow = changeRow + 1
            End If
        Next i
```

Code with With Statment

```
With ws3
    For i = 2 To UBound(data2, 1)
            pernum = Data(i, 2)
            If Not pernums.Exists(pernum) Then
                .Cells(changeRow, 1).Value = pernum
                .Cells(changeRow, 2).Value = "Not Found in the first sheet"
                changeRow = changeRow + 1
            End If
        Next i
End With
```

The Same Code with the With Statment Takes about 15 to 16 Seconds on my Computer.

Getting into the habit of chunking actions into With statements will not only keep your macros running faster but also make it easier to read your macro code.

**Rule #4 Ignore Events**

If you have a Worksheet_Change event implemented for the Sheet1 of your workbook. Any time a cell or range is altered on the Sheet1, the Worksheet_Change event will run. So if you have a standard macro that manipulates several cells on Sheet1, each time a cell on that sheet is changed, your macro has to pause while the Worksheet_Change event runs. You can imagine how this behavior would slow down your macro.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

At the end of your code, you can set the EnableEvents mode back to True with the statement:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Hi, First of all thank you very much. Secondly I implemented all of your suggestions and it runs much faster but still when I run huge excels it takes a long long time. Is there anything more I can do or disable while the macro runs to make the code run faster?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad to hear that things are moving faster now. What kind of times are you talking about when you say that the evaluation takes a long time? Since you have a nested loop (For i = 2 To UBound(data1, 1) contains CompareRows function) without knowing the data and what your exact goal is, it is difficult to optimise further.

Comment: I'm talking about more than 20 minutes when I compare two different sheets with 90,000 rows and 8 columns each. A smaller sheet size of 14,000 rows and 15 columns took around 4 minutes.

Comment: As I said, the nested loop will be the bottleneck. since with 14K rows and 15 columns you are comparing 210K values with 210K values. With 90K rows and 8 columns, there are 720K values being compared. If you just assume that every value is compared to every other value, that's 44m comparisons against 520m comparisons with 90k rows. As I said, it's already optimised, the only way you can make it faster is to optimise the comparison routine, i.e. rewrite the code.

Answer (score 0):

### Log Sheet Changes

[image]

[image]

**Main**

```vb
Sub LogSheetChanges()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Log Sheet Changes"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const FIRST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FIRST_PERNUM_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const SECOND_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet3"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 2
    Const DST_CHANGE_DELIMITER As String = ", "
    Const DST_HEADER_DELIMITER As String = ": "
    Dim dHeaders() As Variant:
    dHeaders = Array("Personal Number", "Explanation")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' First
    
    Dim hrg As Range, fpnrg As Range, hData() As Variant, fData() As Variant
    Dim cCount As Long, frCount As Long
    
    If Not GetFirst(wb, FIRST_SHEET_NAME, FIRST_PERNUM_COLUMN, _
        hrg, fpnrg, hData, fData, cCount, frCount) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Second
        
    Dim spnrg As Range, sData() As Variant, scIndices() As Variant
    Dim srCount As Long, SecondPernumColumn As Long
    
    If Not GetSecond(wb, SECOND_SHEET_NAME, hrg, FIRST_PERNUM_COLUMN, _
        spnrg, sData, scIndices, srCount, SecondPernumColumn) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Indices
    
    Dim fcIndices() As Variant
    
    If Not GetColumnIndices(FIRST_PERNUM_COLUMN, _
        fcIndices, scIndices, cCount) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim srIndices() As Variant: srIndices = Application.Match(fpnrg, spnrg, 0)
    Dim frIndices() As Variant: frIndices = Application.Match(spnrg, fpnrg, 0)
    
    ' Destination Array
    
    Dim dData() As Variant, drCount As Long
    
    If Not PopulateDestinationArray(hData, fData, sData, frIndices, srIndices, _
        fcIndices, scIndices, FIRST_PERNUM_COLUMN, SecondPernumColumn, _
        frCount, srCount, cCount, DST_COLUMNS_COUNT, DST_CHANGE_DELIMITER, _
        DST_HEADER_DELIMITER, dData, drCount) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Destination Range
    
    If Not PopulateDestinationRange(wb, DST_SHEET_NAME, DST_FIRST_CELL, _
        dHeaders, dData, drCount, DST_COLUMNS_COUNT) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Changes logged.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**Help 1**

```vb
Function GetFirst( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal FirstSheetName As String, _
    ByVal FirstPernumColumn As Long, _
    hrg As Range, _
    fpnrg As Range, _
    ByRef hData() As Variant, _
    ByRef fData() As Variant, _
    ByRef cCount As Long, _
    ByRef frCount As Long) _
As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get First"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(FirstSheetName)
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        frCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
        If frCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No data in worksheet """ & ws.Name & """ of workbook """ _
                & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set hrg = .Rows(1)
        hData = hrg.Value
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        With .Resize(frCount).Offset(1)
            Set fpnrg = .Columns(FirstPernumColumn)
            fData = .Value
        End With
    End With

    GetFirst = True
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Help 2**

```vb
Function GetSecond( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal SecondSheetName As String, _
    ByVal hrg As Range, _
    ByVal FirstPernumColumn As Long, _
    spnrg As Range, _
    ByRef sData() As Variant, _
    ByRef scIndices() As Variant, _
    ByRef srCount As Long, _
    ByRef SecondPernumColumn As Long) _
As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get Second"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SecondSheetName)
    
    With ws.UsedRange
         Debug.Print .Address
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
        If srCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No data in worksheet """ & ws.Name & """ of workbook """ _
                & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Function
        End If
        scIndices = Application.Match(hrg, .Rows(1), 0)
        Dim spnc As Variant: spnc = scIndices(FirstPernumColumn)
        If IsNumeric(spnc) Then
            SecondPernumColumn = spnc
        Else
            MsgBox "Second personal number column not found!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Function
        End If
        With .Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
            Set spnrg = .Columns(SecondPernumColumn)
            sData = .Value
        End With
    End With
    
    GetSecond = True
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Help 3**

```vb
Function GetColumnIndices( _
    ByVal FirstPernumColumn As Long, _
    ByRef fcIndices() As Variant, _
    ByRef scIndices() As Variant, _
    ByRef cCount As Long) _
As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get Column Indices"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    ReDim fcIndices(1 To cCount)
    
    Dim fc As Long, sc As Long
    
    For fc = 1 To cCount
        If fc <> FirstPernumColumn Then
            If IsNumeric(scIndices(fc)) Then
                sc = sc + 1
                fcIndices(sc) = fc
                scIndices(sc) = scIndices(fc)
            End If
        End If
    Next fc
    
    If sc = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matching columns found!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    cCount = sc
    
    ReDim Preserve fcIndices(1 To cCount)
    ReDim Preserve scIndices(1 To cCount)
    
    GetColumnIndices = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Help 4**

```vb
Function PopulateDestinationArray( _
    hData() As Variant, _
    fData() As Variant, _
    sData() As Variant, _
    frIndices() As Variant, _
    srIndices() As Variant, _
    fcIndices() As Variant, _
    scIndices() As Variant, _
    ByVal FirstPernumColumn As Long, _
    ByVal SecondPernumColumn As Long, _
    ByVal frCount As Long, _
    ByVal srCount As Long, _
    ByVal cCount As Long, _
    ByVal dcCount As Long, _
    ByVal ChangeDelimiter As String, _
    ByVal HeaderDelimiter As String, _
    ByRef dData() As Variant, _
    ByRef drCount As Long) _
As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Populate Destination Array"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    drCount = frCount + srCount - Application.Count(frIndices)
    ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim cdLen As Long: cdLen = Len(ChangeDelimiter)
    
    Dim fr As Long, sr As Variant, dr As Long, fc As Long, c As Long
    Dim fStr As String, sStr As String, dStr As String, LogNot As Boolean
    
    For fr = 1 To frCount
        sr = srIndices(fr, 1)
        If IsNumeric(sr) Then ' personal found in second
            For c = 1 To cCount
                fc = fcIndices(c)
                fStr = CStr(fData(fr, fc))
                sStr = CStr(sData(sr, scIndices(c)))
                If StrComp(fStr, sStr, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    dStr = dStr & hData(1, fc) & HeaderDelimiter _
                        & fStr & " changed to " & sStr _
                        & ChangeDelimiter
                End If
            Next c
            If Len(dStr) = 0 Then
                LogNot = True
            Else
                dStr = Left(dStr, Len(dStr) - cdLen)
            End If
        Else ' personal not found in second
            dStr = "Not found in second sheet."
        End If
        If LogNot Then
            LogNot = False
        Else
            dr = dr + 1
            dData(dr, 1) = fData(fr, FirstPernumColumn)
            dData(dr, 2) = dStr
            dStr = vbNullString
        End If
    Next fr
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If IsError(frIndices(sr, 1)) Then
            dr = dr + 1
            dData(dr, 1) = sData(sr, SecondPernumColumn)
            dData(dr, 2) = "Not found in first sheet."
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If dr < drCount Then drCount = dr
    
    PopulateDestinationArray = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Help 5**

```vb
Function PopulateDestinationRange( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal SheetName As String, _
    ByVal FirstCellAddress As String, _
    dHeaders() As Variant, _
    dData() As Variant, _
    ByVal drCount As Long, _
    ByVal dcCount As Long) _
As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Populate Destination Range"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    
    With ws.Range(FirstCellAddress).Resize(, dcCount)
        ' Write headers.
        .Value = dHeaders
        ' Write data.
        .Offset(1).Resize(drCount).Value = dData
        ' Clear below.
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row - drCount).Offset(drCount + 1).Clear
        ' Format.
        .Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    PopulateDestinationRange = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```